# CSS/JS: Animate Inline Element Upon Text Change

Tags: javascript, html, css

When an `inline` element's text changes, it is usually the case that its computed `width` or `height` changes as well.

Usually it's trivial to `transition` property changes with CSS, for example, adding a `transition` to change the `background-color` of an element upon hover.

However, `inline` element dimensions are really tricky. A simple `transition` property does not animate the change in computed `width`.

View example an by clicking here: https://jsfiddle.net/mz103/59s42ys4/ or viewing it below:

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
 $(this).text("Although my width changes, it is not aniamted.");
});
```

```css
div {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: red;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 
 transition: width 0.3s; // Notice, this doesn't transition the width upon change.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me.</div>
```

**How, when the text of an `inline` element changes, can we animate those changes?**

Comment: Why the down votes? Please explain and I'll do my best to revise.

Comment: How do you want to animate, can you please explain by an example like how "New Text" from "Here's some text" will appear, as you do not want to use delay in show/hide or transition? I have upvoted you to negate other's downvote, still not clear about your question.

Comment: Also it is better to include your code within your question as well as providing a fiddle

Comment: @Elegant.Scripting, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/ky3c5Lec/3/

Comment: @Thomas this works really nicely, you understood it completely. If you add this add an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thanks I'll  fix that.

Comment: @AnilKumar thanks, I'll revise my question to be more clear.

Comment: The animation happens when the `value` of the **attribute** `width` changes. not when the visual width changes.

Comment: Have tried with `addClass`  and `transition` property it worked this way: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/59s42ys4/1/ Is it something close to your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an Update: https://jsfiddle.net/ky3c5Lec/3/

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    //get the current Dimensions, as Start-value for the animation
    var $this = $(this),
        sw = $this.width(),
        sh = $this.height();

    $this.text("New text");
    var tw = $this.width(),
        th = $this.height();

    $this.css({
        //since jQuery.animate() doesn't have sth. like Tween.from() 
        //we have to reset the styles to the initial values
        width: sw, height: sh
    }).animate({
        //and then animate 
        width: tw, height: th
    }, function(){
        //and when the animation is done, we clean up after ourselves
        $this.css({
            width: "", height: ""
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Nice one, there's a weird behavior though when you click it more than one time the text wraps and it looks like a glitch, to fix it you can use [`$("div").one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `$("div").on()`

Answer (score 1):

You could try a little bit of jQuery animation:

```
function changeText(el) {
    el.animate(
    {
        opacity: 0
    }, 
    {
        duration: 'slow', 
        complete: function () {
            $(this).text('New Text');
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
        }
    });  
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ky3c5Lec/5/).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you will need two elements to achieve this elegantly:

```js
$(".inner").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $par = $this.parent();
  $par.css({
    width: $par.width()
  });

  $this.text("New text");

  $par.css({
    width: $this.outerWidth()
  });

});
```

```css
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Here's some text.</div>
</div>
```