# Animation on content change with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

On my website i change text with JS. This change of text can move the border or can resize the background of the text. This is happening instantly. So my question is how i can make that change smooth with an animation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330080/css-js-animate-inline-element-upon-text-change/35340111#35340111

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var newText= '<p>Quo ridiculus, faucibus?</p>';

  var $text = $('#the-text');

  // get the current height
  var oldHeight = $text.height();

  // change the text and get the new height
  $text.html(newText);
    var newHeight = $text.height();

    // set the height back to the old value
  $text.css({
    height: oldHeight
  });

  // animate to the new height
  $text.animate({height: newHeight}, 500);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohx7nzsh/

So basically:

- You get the current height
- You swap the text
- You get the new height
- You set the height fixed on the old value
- You animate to the new height

Do note you'll need an `overflow: hidden` on the text element, like I did in the fiddle.